# How can I compress svg file?

Tags: html, css, svg, compression, minify

I have a svg file with size 2.7 MB. It's too big because it's accessible on the website for a long time. So I need to compress it. I want to compress it to 200 kb. I looked for some tools online in Google, but I did not find a tool that can compress svg with a certain size

I try https://vecta.io/nano, https://www.svgminify.com/ etc. But that can't be

How can I solve this problem?

**Update** :

My svg file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none slice" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1000" height="400" viewBox="0 102 795 400" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="900" height="500" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAeACAYAAAAvokrGAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN
AAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAA
CXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AACAAElEQVR42uz92YLsuq5giwGM3Kfq1rX//wds/6FdddbMIPwg
NmCnJiKymbHG2FtrRkoUxb4BSFDNTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4O8n/.......AmoAAGAAARU5ErkJggg==" />
</svg>
```

**Note** :
`.......` a very long code

Previously I did the conversion from png to svg

Comment: @Mister Jojo if I use webp, I can't customize the image like svg file

Comment: [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) is still really good at what it does. Worth a try.

Comment: In order to reduce the size of the file you can do several things: You may try to optimize the code. Also you can try to remove unnecessary data, You can save part of it as a rastre image and use it as a image element or as a background. You can also minify the data. It would be nice to see what you have

Comment: @enxaneta I update my question. Look at that. I try to remove some section. But it's the same. Seems I must to remove `data:image/png;base64`. But if I remove it, the image is not show

Comment: Why should do such a thing? If you want a raster image use it as an image `<img>`

Comment: @enxaneta I have a png file. I want to custom it. And then I conver it to svg file use https://www.aconvert.com/image/png-to-svg/. The result like that

Comment: Look here > https://askubuntu.com/questions/638072/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-svg-using-software-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @SuccessMan you got any solution ?